# OpsHub VSOnline Migration Utility

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We are researching some of our options to migrate our code from TFS to Team Services.  Currently we are trying to utilize the OpsHub Migration Utility (free version).  I've been able to get everything set up to the point where you have to map users.  At this point I get the following error:

---

**Error message**

```
com.opshub.eai.tfs.exception.IOMTFSApiExcpetion:
OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getUserListForProjects.
Server Error: Multiple identities found matching 'Administrator'. Please specify one of the following identities:
- Administrator ([DOMAIN_NAME]\Administrator)([DOMAIN_NAME]\Administrator)
- Administrator ([SERVER_NAME]\Administrator)([SERVER_NAME]\Administrator)
```

**Stack from log file:**

```
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IdentityManagementService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor searchFactor, String factorValue, MembershipQuery queryMembership, ReadIdentityOptions readOptions)
at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSCommonUtility.getUserListForProjects(String[] selectedProjects) in d:\Trunk\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSCommonUtility.cs:line 482
at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.getUserListForProjects(String authToken, String[] selectedProjects) in d:\Trunk\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line 532
at SyncInvokegetUserListForProjects(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)*
```

---

When I click OK in the message box, I have no option to specify one of these accounts (as the message states) and both the source and destination lists remain empty.

I also noticed while scouring the web for a solution that the free version no longer supports impersonation for user mapping.  If this is in fact the case, wouldn't this mapping step be irrelevant when using the free utility?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a bug indeed. You can solve it by either fixing the source database (which seems to be migrated from one domain to another in an incorrect way) or by waiting for OpsHub to publish a fix and restart the migration.

Comment: You may also want to contact Microsoft to get on the waitlist for a high fidelity migration (upload your backup of TFS). But that will require you to be on the latest version of TFS (2015u3) and to have upgraded your process template to be in line with the latest VS-Team-Services process templates.

Comment: OpsHub really don't like to support this tool and would rather you buy their commercial tool.

Comment: Hi, is your source  TFS version 2010? This is a known issue for tfs2010, due to the Identity Management API that we use. Let me get back to you on a possible fix/workaround. (Also, the user mapping is used for setting fields of User Type for WIT, apart from impersonation, hence it is taken as an input)